# Going deeper into a website while web scraping

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a bunch of websites for text so that I can cross validate with a corpus and display the number of hits particular words have on those websites.
Can someone please help me with making my web scraper go deeper into the website automatically.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.theleela.com/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa/'
page = requests.get(url)        #to extract page from website
html = page.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
```

I call for all the links on the webpage like this :

```
links=[]
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
  a = link.get('href')
  if type(a) == str and "https:" not in a:
    links.append(a)
links
```

This is what I get:

```
['/en_us/offers/index',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-bengaluru/the-leela-palace-hotel-bengaluru',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-bengaluru/the-leela-palace-hotel-bengaluru/overview',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-bengaluru/the-leela-palace-hotel-bengaluru/rooms-and-suites',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-bengaluru/the-leela-palace-hotel-bengaluru/offers',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-bengaluru/the-leela-palace-hotel-bengaluru/meetings',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-bengaluru/the-leela-palace-hotel-bengaluru/celebrations',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-bengaluru/the-leela-palace-hotel-bengaluru/dining',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-bengaluru/the-leela-palace-hotel-bengaluru/Spa',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-chennai/the-leela-palace-hotel-chennai',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-chennai/the-leela-palace-hotel-chennai/overview',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-chennai/the-leela-palace-hotel-chennai/rooms-and-suites',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-chennai/the-leela-palace-hotel-chennai/offers',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-chennai/the-leela-palace-hotel-chennai/meetings',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-chennai/the-leela-palace-hotel-chennai/celebrations',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-chennai/the-leela-palace-hotel-chennai/dining',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-chennai/the-leela-palace-hotel-chennai/spa',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-palace-hotel-new-delhi',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-palace-hotel-new-delhi/overview',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-palace-hotel-new-delhi/rooms-and-suites',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-palace-hotel-new-delhi/offers',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-palace-hotel-new-delhi/meetings',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-palace-hotel-new-delhi/celebrations',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-palace-hotel-new-delhi/dining',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-palace-hotel-new-delhi/spa',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-ambience-convention-hotel-delhi',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-ambience-convention-hotel-delhi/overview',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-ambience-convention-hotel-delhi/rooms-and-suites',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-ambience-convention-hotel-delhi/offers',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-ambience-convention-hotel-delhi/meetings',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-ambience-convention-hotel-delhi/celebrations',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-ambience-convention-hotel-delhi/dining',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-delhi/the-leela-ambience-convention-hotel-delhi/spa',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-goa/the-leela-goa-hotel',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-goa/the-leela-goa-hotel/overview',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-goa/the-leela-goa-hotel/rooms-and-suites',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-goa/the-leela-goa-hotel/offers',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-goa/the-leela-goa-hotel/meetings',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-goa/the-leela-goa-hotel/celebrations',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-goa/the-leela-goa-hotel/dining',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-goa/the-leela-goa-hotel/spa',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-gurugram/the-leela-ambience-hotel-gurugram',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-gurugram/the-leela-ambience-hotel-gurugram/overview',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-gurugram/the-leela-ambience-hotel-gurugram/rooms-and-suites',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-gurugram/the-leela-ambience-hotel-gurugram/offers',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-gurugram/the-leela-ambience-hotel-gurugram/meetings',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-gurugram/the-leela-ambience-hotel-gurugram/celebrations',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-gurugram/the-leela-ambience-hotel-gurugram/dining',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-gurugram/the-leela-ambience-hotel-gurugram/spa',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-kovalam/the-leela-kovalam-hotel',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-kovalam/the-leela-kovalam-hotel/overview',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-kovalam/the-leela-kovalam-hotel/rooms-and-suites',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-kovalam/the-leela-kovalam-hotel/offers',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-kovalam/the-leela-kovalam-hotel/meetings',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-kovalam/the-leela-kovalam-hotel/celebrations',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-kovalam/the-leela-kovalam-hotel/dining',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-kovalam/the-leela-kovalam-hotel/spa',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/overview',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/rooms-and-suites',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/offers',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/meetings',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/celebrations',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/dining',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-udaipur/the-leela-palace-hotel-udaipur',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-udaipur/the-leela-palace-hotel-udaipur/overview',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-udaipur/the-leela-palace-hotel-udaipur/rooms-and-suites',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-udaipur/the-leela-palace-hotel-udaipur/offers',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-udaipur/the-leela-palace-hotel-udaipur/meetings',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-udaipur/the-leela-palace-hotel-udaipur/celebrations',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-udaipur/the-leela-palace-hotel-udaipur/dining',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-udaipur/the-leela-palace-hotel-udaipur/spa',
 'javascript:facebookLogin();',
 'javascript:forgot_password(this);',
 '/application/spring/myprofile/my-profile-edit',
 '/en_us',
 '/application/spring/myprofile/login',
 '/the-leela/best-rates-guaranteed',
 '#',
 'javascript:facebookLogin();',
 '/application/spring/myprofile/my-profile-edit',
 '/en_us',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa/signature-spa-treatments-',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa/holistic-treatments-',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa/fitness',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa/wellness',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa/salon',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa/signature-spa-treatments-',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa/holistic-treatments-',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa/fitness',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa/wellness',
 '/en_us/hotels-in-mumbai/the-leela-mumbai-hotel/spa/salon',
 '/contentAsset/raw-data/d1e3f704-be84-4353-a95e-28629651db00/fileAsset',
 '/the-leela/about-the-leela/history',
 '/the-leela/about-the-leela/company-information',
 '/the-leela/about-the-leela/alliances',
 '/the-leela/about-the-leela/investor-relations',
 '/the-leela/about-the-leela/future-openings',
 'javascript:void(0);',
 '/the-leela/media/media-coverage',
 '/the-leela/media/press-releases',
 '/the-leela/media/media-contacts',
 '/the-leela/media/the-leela-magazine',
 '/the-leela/media/awards',
 '/the-leela/Loyalty/the-leela-discovery',
 '/the-leela/Loyalty/leela-solitaire-line',
 '/the-leela/Loyalty/connoisseur-club',
 '/the-leela/Loyalty/the-leela-preferred-partners-membership-program',
 '/the-leela/careers/opportunities',
 '/the-leela/contact-us/hotels',
 '/the-leela/contact-us/convention-centre',
 '/the-leela/contact-us/reservations',
 '/the-leela/contact-us/sales-marketing-offices',
 'javascript:void(0);',
 '/the-leela/others/art',
 '/the-leela/others/boutique',
 '/the-leela/termsConditions/legal',
 '/the-leela/termsConditions/siteMap',
 '/the-leela/termsConditions/privacy-policy',
 '/the-leela/termsConditions/general-terms-and-conditions']
```

As you can see there are still some irrelevant links here

```
'javascript:void(0);',
/application/spring/myprofile/login',
 '/the-leela/best-rates-guaranteed',
 '#',
 'javascript:facebookLogin();',
 '/application/spring/myprofile/my-profile-edit',
 '/en_us',
```

I need help getting rid of these so that I can run the scraper on a loop on the output list. Appreciate any help.

Comment: So you're basically asking how to strip a list of elements that don't start with '/'?

Comment: @BoboDarph some of the elements in his list of undesirables started with `/`

Comment: You can't, since this particular example: ```'/the-leela/best-rates-guaranteed'``` is the same as the links you want. What you can do is remove 'javascript...' and '/en_us' looking for double '/' pattern

Comment: Links with ```profile``` and ```login``` on it as well...

Comment: You would have to actually define what's considered "irrelevant".  In this case, the `/application/spring...` and `/en_us` links looks valid just as well.  There's nothing "automatic" about programming, it's all what you tell the program to do.  So you must first have a clear separation between what's "relevant" and what's not before you can code the script to do so for you.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's a ready-available solution which is not a site-specific. Based on my experience with crawlers a few things came to my mind:

- You may use site's [sitemap](https://www.theleela.com/the-leela/termsConditions/siteMap/) page which is usually there for likeminded crawlers and would contain links to all the important pages the site owners want you to crawl. [`robots.txt`](https://www.theleela.com/robots.txt) could also be useful.
- You may try to download all the pages and use [`mimetypes`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/mimetypes.html) lib and/or even utilize `Content-Type` header
- You may want to put some heuristic keywords or rules, like regular expressions, to prevent your crawler from reaching or crawling certain URLs.
- Finally (if that's a huge multi-month project for many hundreds or thousands websites) you may try to further limit URLs using machine learning.